# Classification based on List of Words Python

Tags: python, mongodb, classification, words

I would like to classify text: Positive, Negative or Neutral. I have a positive and negative list of words. I want to do it in  Python. Here I describe in this kind of code

> if word in text found in positive_words then 
>   counterpos = pos_count[i] += 1
>
> if word in text found in negative_words then 
>   counterneg = neg_count[i] += 1
>
> totalcount = pos_count + neg_count
>
> if(len(totalcount) > 0):
>       store in positive database 
>   elif (len(totalcount) < 0):
>       store in negative database else:
>
> ```
> store in neutral database
> ```

This is the general idea, my coding hability is null. 
i am storing in mongodb so that part i have no problem storing. Still i cant do the classification.
Can someone please help me.

Comment: This is not a very difficult task, after reading some tutorials on strings and control flow statements you can do it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html & https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html and for mongodb http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/

Comment: Yeah I am aware that python is very easy to learn, the thing is i have time pressure and can't get my stuff together, thank youu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to string comparisons and control flow statements, a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) will be useful here.

```
text = "seeking help on possible homework task"
raw_words = text.split(" ")

positive_words = ['seeking','help']
negative_words = ['homework']

positive_score = len([word for word in raw_words if word in positive_words])
negative_score = len([word for word in raw_words if word in negative_words])

total_score = positive_score - negative_score
```

This would result in `total_score` having a value of `1`.